# Fetch Value from Listbox Datasource

Tags: c#, database, winforms, data-binding

I have a list box that is data bound to a accdb file and is display the contents of one column, the dataBindingSource that it is linked to has also been filtered - this works fine (but may effect what I'm about to ask).

I would like to know how to pull a value from the selected items full record, for example. The list box currently displays the surname - that is all you can see, how can I pull the customers forename which isn't displayed but does exist within the data bound source?

This is the code used the populate the list box:

```
    public frmCustomer(string Input)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.customersTableAdapter.Fill(this.dSSystem.Customers);
        this.catsTableAdapter.Fill(this.dSSystem.Cats);

        // Display Customer Record
        int lvRecIdx = customersBindingSource.Find("AccRef", Input);
        customersBindingSource.Position = lvRecIdx;

        // Fetch Cats Owned
        catsBindingSource.Filter = ("CustRef = '" + Input + "'");
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Please also show us some code and make sure to attach the tag for WPF / Asp.NET / WinForms, so you will get the right answer.

Comment: you should select 2 column from datasource in this case access database. You should also select `primary key` of the table.

Comment: @FabianBigler I currently don't have any code to show as I'm not sure on how I would reference another field within that record, I have added the code used to populate the list box if that helps.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi The list box wont allow me to select more than one column to display, is this what you're asking me to do?

Comment: @MoonPunch every item in the listbox has two main property: `Value`, `Text`. Value does not show to end user, but Text will be shown to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ListBox` contains of two members: A **ValueMember** and a **DisplayMember**.

You could define a simple object which you are filling from your data base query:

```
 public class SomeItem
 {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string DisplayText { get; set; }
        public string Column1 { get; set; }
        public string Column2 { get; set; }
        ...etc...
 }
```

Your implementation could look something like this (some mockup data):

```
   var items = new List<SomeItem>();
   var item = new SomeItem();
   item.Key ="key1";
   item.DisplayText = "value1";
   item.Column1 = "col1";
   item.Column2 = "col2";
   items.Add(item);
   listBox1.DataSource = items;
   listBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayText"; //User will see your DisplayText
   listBox1.ValueMember = "Key"; //The key which is unique and your Primary Key on your database
```

Then based on the value you selected, you can query through your items and get the item:

```
   var key = (int)listBox1.SelectedValue;
   foreach (var existingItem in items)
   {
            if (existingItem.Key == key)
            {
                //woohoo got it!
               Debug.Print(existingItem.Column1)
               Debug.Print(existingItem.Column2)
            }
   }
```