# getting a select statement column info from combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Hopefully i don't sound confusing but i am not sure if what i am trying to get at is possible.

I have a select statement to get name, id, guid. I am setting the display to name and the value to Id for each combobox. Is there a way that i could also assign the guid to the combo box so that i could use it in my winforms app?

here is what i have for select statement:

```
private void secondChild_drp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string secondChildId = secondChild_drp.SelectedValue.ToString();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ... WHERE em.ChildID = (" + secondChildId + ")", conString))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                thirdChild_drp.ValueMember = "ID";
                thirdChild_drp.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
                thirdChild_drp.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
        cmd.CommandText="StoreProcName";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildID", secondChildId);
        cmd.Connection = con2;
        con2.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var guid = reader.ToString();
        reader.Close();
        con2.Close();
    }
```

right now when i run this it tells me `reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` has `Procedure or function StoreProcName has too many arguments specified.`

i just want to get the guid associated with the id i passed in.

Comment: you mean 2 value members?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly. We might give you a workaround?

Comment: @EhsanUllah i want to get the guid for the combo box item - i am not using the id for security reasons. and individual can guess ids but hard to guess guids. i am using the guid of selected item to display further detailed information

Comment: you have all the data in dt containing the id and guid?

Comment: see my answer below and let me know if you meant something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the guid from your datatable as follows where yourselectedid is the combobox selecteditem id.

```
var results = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
where row.Field<int>("ID") == yourselectedid
select row;
```

now from results you can get all the desired columns you want

Comment: So i actually created a stored procedure that will give the guid when i pass in the id

Comment: so when i create a var to get that do i create that within the `using` statement ?

Comment: @Masriyah no you will have to save your datatable somewhere so that is available to you when selected item is changed in combobox. and then you can query it later to get Guids.

Comment: @Masriyah just an after thought you can also do it like this DataTable dt = comboBox1.DataSource as DataTable; and then you can query your dt without saving it at class level.

Comment: I will update my post with what i have so far and then we can take a look. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @Masriyah yeah go a head.

Comment: I went ahead and updated it. This is what i am trying to use this part for. I have four comboboxes each with an id and name and guid. I am using the id to populate other comboboxes and i will be using the guid for each combo to build a path so when i am uploading it will show a path of four guids. Currently i am showing one combo box  and trying to get its guid and then apply the same for the others.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34486/discussion-between-ehsan-ullah-and-masriyah)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same answer as I already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953261/fetch-value-from-listbox-datasource/17953527#17953527):

You could define a simple object which you are filling from your data base query:

```
 public class Item
 {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public Guid Guid{ get; set; }
 }
```

Your implementation could look something like this (some mockup data):

```
   listBox1.DataSource = items;
   listBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
   listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Then based on the value you selected, you can query through your items and get the item:

```
   var key = (int)listBox1.SelectedValue;
   foreach (var existingItem in items)
   {
            if (existingItem.Key == key)
            {
                //woohoo got it!
               Debug.Print(existingItem.Guid.ToString())
            }
   }
```

Comment: `listBox1.DataSource = items;` where is items coming from?

Comment: @Masriyah Have a look at the complete answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can put both of the value in the value member, separated by whichever character for separator like : "12;0000-000-0000" then separate again the Value Menber with a String.Split.